# Zipped java files appear as a single line

Tags: java, zip

I'm being sent some java code as Zip files, however, when I unzip them, it's a giant, illegible line of code.

I've tried sending the Zip via different mediums

Comment: Do not open with notepad.

Answer (score 1):

This probably means the Java source file has a different line ending convention (LF vs. CRLF) than your local computer. If you use a decent text editor it will pick that up and display it correctly. Otherwise you can run a line-end converter to fix it up.

Answer (score 0):

The software you use for reading the file might not handle correctly the original text format of the file causing line breaks to get lost. Depending on the operative system and the software used to create the file line breaks might be generated using only one LF (line feed) character (i.e. Linux) or in other cases it might need a combination of CR (carriage return) plus LF characters (i.e. windows) to represent the line break.

Try opening it with a more advanced text editor and you might be able to recover the missing line breaks.

Comment: Ok, then the problem is probably that the code was written using eclipse on a mac and read using eclipse on a windows PC?

Comment: There is a chance it could be, try using notepad++ to identify the broken line breaks. Open the file there and press the icon that looks like this:¶ symbol in the toolbar

It will help you visualize the missing line breaks and you can replace them with the one that work for your OS